# Dynamically adding TableCells to TableRow, fails to add more cells after N times

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In my VB class, I have about 90 fields and unknown number of rows to add to my (system.web.ui.webcontrol)table.
The table is created while the data reader loops.

```
Dim table As Table
table = New Table 
Dim row As New TableRow
Dim cell As New TableCell 
row = New TableRow
```

I repeatedly used this code to add the fields.

> col1, col2,col3 ...

```
cell = New TableCell
cell.Text = "col1"
row.Cells.Add(co)
```

At the end of each data row, it will add using

```
table.Rows.Add(row)
```

At about the 62nd column/cell, all remaining cells just pile up at the last column.

> ... col60, col61col62col63...

No errors in the code.
Results comes back normally, except around the 62nd column all column names and data are being dumped into it.

I commented out the parts that being dumped, and put them back one by one.
It only confirms where it starts.

I tried shorter names but results stays the same.
I have not added the rows yet, so that rules out the row numbers.

I have been looking for answers but no luck.
If I hit the limit on how many I can add, but I seen no articles on how many cells you add.
There are some articles mentioning data limit but I am only on the creation of the table header.

Is there a way add more columns to the row without remaining columns jammed at the last one?

Comment: It is unclear what platform you are using… WPF, Winforms… other? However, typically you would NOT be adding individual cells to a table. Once the columns are defined, then you simply add the rows. Adding the row typically would “automatically” create the individual cells. Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: @JohnG I am adding a vb class to be called in a vb program to send email. I am defining the columns to be rendered in the email. So far, title columns are only added. depending on the data returned rows will be added.

Comment: Again, I am sorry if I am missing something, However, I am not sure how “email” comes into play in relation to adding cells to a table.

Comment: @JohnG The table results are used to be the body of the email, that part is good. I will have to remove that in the question.

Comment: [Table Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/table-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) -> [How to: Build a Table Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-build-a-table-programmatically?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) & Co.

Comment: I initially thought it was caused by having long column names. All the names with length of 15-20 characters. The last column renders all remaing column names in the last columns, like it concatenates  them.

Comment: @Jimi I have seen that, table works if only less then 60 columns added. beyond that all data and colmun names are dumped into the 60th column.

Comment: Can you show the code that adds the columns and rows to the table? And clarify what platform you are using… WPF, Winforms ...other? I am just saying that I have never seen a “table” type data construct that is limited to only 60 columns.

Comment: @JohnG I can't give the exact code, but I try to provide as much as I can when I get back to the office.  The platform is winforms in vb.net. the data is from data reader looping to generate rows. its not exactly happening in 60th column but more like around 62nd. I have used same code structures before but with less number of columns. this one have me stumped.

Comment: `Table`, `TableRow` and `TableCell` are not part of the Windows Forms assemblies, you need Presentation Framework assemblies. Or an ElementHost that contains a WPF UserControl. Or you have third-party assemblies that use Presentation Framework or use the same class names. You need to clarify what tools you have before anything else. -- The number of Columns that can be presented in the current view may depend on the Container (the UI Element that contains the Table - See in the Docs which containers are suitable for the Table element. Not any)

Comment: I ended up using stringbuilder to create html table. but the result is the same. My conclusion is that its not the table but the way outlook interprets the table. Thank you.